# Get data con Laravel y Guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, response

Estoy necesitando parsear una api y obtener solo 2 datos de todo lo que responde, pero no estoy logrando pasarlo a la vista...

Si hago un `dd($dataFinal)`, se muestra todo el json pero no logro pasar a la vista solo los datos que necesito.

```
public function index()
{

    $url= "ACA_URL";
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->get($url);
    $content = (string) $res->getBody();

    $dataFinal = json_decode($content, true);
    
    return view("test", ["dataFinal" => $dataFinal,]);
}
```

mi `dd()` responde esto:

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "usuario":{
      "nro_evento":2960505,
      "nro_secuencia_contacto":1,
      "Tipo_contacto":{
         "Cod_contacto":1,
         "Descripcion":null,
         "Visible":null,
         "Representante":0
      },
      "den_user":20359193360,
      "tipo_den":0,
      "Tipo_den_desc":null,
      "nro_den":"00001894",
      "denominacion":"Usuario",
      "telefono":0,
      "celular":0,
      "proveedor_celular":0,
      "mail":"",
      "cod_area_tel":"",
      "cod_area_cel":"",
      "HabilitadoUso":true
   }
}
```

Y esta es mi view la cual no logro hacer funcionar.

```
@foreach($dataFinal['usuario'] as $nota) {
    $denominacion = "";
    $nro_den = "";

    @foreach ($nota as $key => $value) 
    {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'denominacion':
                $denominacion = $value;
                break;
            case 'nro_den':
                $nro_den = $value;
                break;
        }
        
    }
    @endforeach

    echo "<p>Cliente: " . $denominacion . " " . $nro_den . "</p>";
};
@endforeach
```

Necesito que en la vista necesito mostrar ·`denominacion` y `nro_den`...

Esto lo pude hacer funcionar en php puro, pero no logro pasarlo a laravel.

Desde ya muchisimas gracias <3

Error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona? Te lanza algún error?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  perdon no habia puesto el error

Comment: Ok. En principio, creo que tienes errores de sintaxis, los `@foreach` en blade no llevan llaves `{}`, y esos `switch` y  `echo` posiblemente también, pues no están dentro de una directiva `@php`. Luego la lógica está rara, pues asignas `$denominacion = ""` y luego en el switch quieres compararlo con `$value`. En fin, prueba simplemente así `@foreach($dataFinal['usuario'] as $nota) {{ "<p>Cliente: {$nota['denominacion']} nro: {$nota['nro_den']}</p>" }} @endforeach` a ver que pasa.

Comment: Hola, gracias por el tiempo, si es que me termine haciendo lio de tanto modificarlo... haciendolo asi me da Undefined index: denominacion

Comment: Ok. Y así? `{{ "<p>Cliente: {$dataFinal['usuario']['denominacion']} nro: {$dataFinal['usuario']['nro_den']}</p>" }}`

Comment: bien si me devuelve los datos pero repetidos <p>Cliente: USUARIOTEST nro: 123456</p> <p>Cliente: USUARIOTEST  nro: 123456</p>

Comment: ahh okok entendi, era solo ese código, millones de gracias! ahora a estudiarlo a ver porqué no me funcionaba para no volver a cometer el mismo error <3 GENIO!!!

Comment: Dale. En resumen, no necesitas el foreach pues podés directamente acceder a los elementos del array.

Comment: Creo que el error original es que hacías dos `foreach`  pero la data que buscas tiene sólo un nivel de profundidad.